# Changing CSS Position not Moving Object on Screen

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag with the id "right_column", and in my css, I can change the position value of it, except when I change the left value, it doesn't move.

Here is my html & CSS. If you run the code snippet, it won't work properly because of the PHP, though.

```css
html {
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
#main_image {
  max-width: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 120px;
}
#right_column {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 50%;
}
#title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* fbfad6 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.details_header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}
.description {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<img id="main_image" src="image/PHP_CODE.png" />
<div id="right_column">
<span id="title"><?php echo $name ?></span>
<div class="details_wrap">
  <table id="details">
    <tr>
      <td class="details_header">Price</td>
      <td class="details_header">Saving</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$
        <?php echo $price ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $saving ?>%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <span><?php echo $description ?><br><br></span>
  <span><?php echo $description2 ?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I feel I may be missing something incredibly obvious, and if so, sorry for wasting your time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can see the result [here](http://discountpenguin.host56.com/product.php)

-Luke

Comment: Why are you trying to position everything absolute?

Comment: @MrYodaylay, the `img` tag at the top of your html code snippet was open. I closed it, but feel free to rollback or re-edit if you disagree with my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example your img id is not closed

```css
html {
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
#main_image {
  max-width: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 120px;
}
#right_column {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 50%;
}
#title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* fbfad6 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.details_header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}
.description {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<img id="main_image" src="image/<?php echo $uuid ?>.png"> <div id="right_column">

<div id="right_column">
<span id="title"><?php echo $name ?></span>
<div class="details_wrap">
  <table id="details">
    <tr>
      <td class="details_header">Price</td>
      <td class="details_header">Saving</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$
        <?php echo $price ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $saving ?>%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <span><?php echo $description ?><br><br></span>
  <span><?php echo $description2 ?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I copied your code to a pen and changed the left value successfully.

http://codepen.io/cdcampbell26/pen/YPNryP

```
#right_column {
      position: relative;
      top: 120px;
      left: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Really don't know why this is happening, as you can see in the link, it won't move there. http://discountpenguin.host56.com/product.php

Comment: @MrYodaylay  Your img id is not closed.  <img id="main_image" src="image/1.png"

Comment: But it is, <img id="main_image" src="image/<?php>>, is the php interfering with it?

Comment: I can pull up the HTML code for your page source on your discount pinguin page.  Where the code reads <!--Main Body: Information , picture, etc.-->

    <img id="main_image" src="image/1.png"  you must put an end bracket like this > after your .png"

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now, will fix that now.

Comment: That should solve your problem.  If it works, please approve my original answer as the correct one.

Comment: @JakeTaylor That's really weird, in Dreamweaver the close bracket > was there, but when I saved the file, closed dreamweaver and opened it again, the > was gone. I guess it wasn't actually there, but it was being displayed in the editor. Thanks for your help anyway, though. It's all working now.